# adding images in uibutton programmaticaly in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Im new to iphone development. i tried to develope button with image (when i click button the image will displayed) this application will developed like programmaticaly in iphone.

Can any one plz help me for my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this:

```
UIImage *newButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageInMyProject.png"];
//Create image object from bundle. Name must include filetype; is case sensetive.

[myButton setImage:newButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 //Set the image for the button when it is in it's default state.
```

This way of doing things is great, because you can set the image to show up differently as needed. The different UIControlStates can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState

Happy coding :)